# Navigate on 401 Http Failure

Tags: javascript, angular

### Issue

I currently have an auth guard in my Angular application that is making a call to my API to check the users' role and returning it back to check whether or not they have access to a specific endpoint.

The tricky part is that when they log out the JWT gets cleared from the local storage in the browser. So when the guard calls the API to check if the token is valid the API returns a 401 Unauthorized.

Now I am trying to catch the 401 error and re-direct the user to the login screen but I am unable to do so, I have tried adding the following in my `catchError` method:

`setTimeout(() => this.router.navigate(['/login']));`

`this.router.navigate(['/login'])`

And just returning false so that the calling method can handle it but none of these worked.

So what I am basically trying to do is just redirect the user to the login page when they receive a 401 Unauthorized on the HTTP call.

### Code

```
export class GuardianGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private http: HttpClient
    ) { }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
        //Get the users role from the API based on the JWT they were authenticated with
        return this.http.get(`${AppSettings.API_ENDPOINT}/Role`).pipe(
            map(data => {
                //Check if the returned server role is that of the guardian
                if (data === "3") {
                    //Allow the action if it is
                    return true;
                } else {
                    //Return to login and deny action if it is not
                    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
                    return false;
                }
            }), catchError(this.handleError));
    }

    private handleError(error: any) : Observable<boolean> {
        setTimeout(() => this.router.navigate(['/login']));
        return of(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: are you getting any errors, or what happens? `I am unable to do so` isn't really explanatory. So what happens instead of the routing?

Answer (score 0):

Its better that you can have the service logic in some Auth service. And can check authorization as below:-

Also you can handle the 401 redirection condition in AuthService only.

```
canActivate(): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
if (this.auth.isAuthorized()) {
  this.router.navigate([CONFIG.routes.login]);
  return false;
} else {
  return true;
}
```